# Find out which user starts a root process in Linux

Tags: linux, process, root

Say someone runs `htop` with sudo:

```
$sudo htop
```

I know we can get the user name of the `htop` process by:

```
$ps aux | grep htop
```

But in this case it only returns root as the username:

```
$ps aux | grep htop
root      21186  0.0  0.0  71256  4148 pts/2    S+   17:16   0:00 sudo htop
root      21187  2.6  0.0  31460  5128 pts/2    S+   17:16   0:21 htop
```

How can I find out which user is behind `root`?

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you. It grabs the commands executed with sudo from `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
awk '/sudo/&&/COMMAND/ {
    print gensub(/sudo: ([^ ]*).*USER=([^ ]*).*COMMAND=([^ ]*)/,
                 "\\1 (as \\2) command: \\3", 1)
}' /var/log/auth.log
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use `grep` on `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/auth.log` (depends on the distro):

```
$ sudo grep sudo /var/log/secure
```

(or)

```
$ sudo grep sudo /var/log/auth.log
```

If these two doesn't work then use `sudo journalctl _COMM=sudo`

It will give output as:

```
Apr 14 00:23:35 hell-abhi sudo[14519]: hell_abhi : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/hell_abhi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl _COMM=sudo
Apr 14 00:21:43 hell-abhi sudo[14348]: hell_abhi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/hell_abhi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/nano
```

The table shows: date, time, user, pid, teminal, directory, command used.

Here you can see: hell_abhi ran `sudo nano` from `/home/hell_abhi`(his home directory).